# Weird behaviour of CLT's application to binomial.

Tags: statistics, problem-solving, statistical-inference, estimation, central-limit-theorem

I am carrying out the simulations of the following experiment for all $n$ in the set $\{1,2,3,...,100\}$.

(0) Set $k=0$.

(1) Generate $n$ $Bernoulli(0.9)$ trials.

(2) Construct estimate $\hat\theta=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i$.

(3) Construct confidence interval of $95\%$, i.e. 
$$\bigg[\hat\theta-\frac{\sqrt{\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)}}{\sqrt{n}}\Phi^{-1}(0.975), \ \ \hat\theta+\frac{\sqrt{\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)}}{\sqrt{n}}\Phi^{-1}(0.975)\bigg]$$

(4) Check whether $0.9$ is in the confidence interval. If yes, add $1$ to $k$.

(5) Repeat steps $1-4$ 100,000 times and calculate $k/100,000$.

Now, I would expect that accordingly to the Central Limit Theorem, as $n$ is bigger, the simulation would be more reasonable (common saying that $n>30$ would suffice), that is I would expect to get something around $0.95$ through the simulation. But when I plotted a graph of $n$ on the x-axis and the value obtained in the 5'th step of simulation (i.e. $k/100,000$), I have observed a very strange behaviour (see picture below). Could anyone explain it?

[image]

Below is the same simulation procedure but for $Bernoulli(0.5)$ rather than $0.9$.

[image]

Below is the graph of the simulation with $Bernoulli(0.9)$ with t-statistic rather than Normal.

[image]

Comment: 0. Since you are estimating the mean, you should be using -statistics, I think. 1. What is on the x-axis and why does it go upto a 100 only? 2. You should be calculating/plotting a running ratio $k_i/i$ instead.

Comment: On x-axis are the values of $n$. I have chosen it to go up to 100. The simulation (steps 0-5) are carried for each value of $n$.

Comment: $k_i/100,000$ because it is a simulation, which should result in ~$0.95$.

Comment: @A.S. I have added the graph for the same simulation, but with $Bernoulli(0.5)$. It doesn't have so big steps.

Comment: You should be using $t$-statistics instead. For low $n$, when $p$ is close to $0,1$ it takes a while to converges - the variance is large compared to the mean (or 1-mean).

Comment: @A.S. I have added the next graph, where I used t-statistic for simulation. It still looks quite similar. Where do these steps come from?

Comment: $B(n,p)$ doesn't start to look normal until $n\min(p,1-p)$ is at least $5$ and more like $10$ (which is exactly $n=100$). When $p$ is small and $np$ is order $1$, it looks like a Poisson instead. The big drops are very unexpected and probably come from some discretization weirdness. It's also interesting that you have exactly 5 drops out of 100. No explanation.

Comment: @A.S. Would you like me to give you the code, so that you could check it for yourself?

Comment: Imagine that there are "gates" outside of which $k$ would not be increased. As you increase $n$, these gates move around a bit, but your DISCRETE binomial moves around as well and when a value jumps from being within the gates to outside of them, you get a drop. Inbetween drops you simply have growth of the central mass without any gate/boundary "crossings" - so you get a steady growth followed by discrete drops.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you! I have discovered the issue with that. If the value of the estimate is $1$, then the confidence interval is of length zero and so $k$ is not increased. Do you know how to handle the estimator if we observe such data that our estimate is 1?

Comment: These are just discritization issues and point you to the fact that if you have "low probability" events that have considerable contribution to the mean, then you need enough sample to make sure those intervals are sampled from and your variable is reduced enough. The mean of $\hat \theta$ is $p$ (but what matters is $1-p<p$ in this case) while the std is $n^{-1/2}\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, so the ratio is $= \sqrt{\frac {p} {(1-p)n}}\approx\sqrt{\frac {10}n}$, so to make it small (say $\frac 1 3$) you need $n\approx 100$.

Comment: In this problem, since you explicitly distribution $\hat \theta_n\sim\frac 1 n B(n,p)$, you can easily compute which values of $\hat\theta_n$ produce a covering confidence interval and just sum probabilities of those values of $\hat\theta$. You will notice the boundary crossing behavior I mentioned.

Comment: @A.S. Could you try to explain it a little bit more? It seems to be a very interesting topic, but I can't get my head around it. Let's take two values on $n$ between which the drop occurs. For $n=29$ the value of $k/100,000$ is very close to $0.95$, but for $n=30$ the value is about $0.8$. How could we explicitly calculate that?

Comment: $\hat\theta_n$ takes values $\frac i n$. Those of the values that fall within some $[a_n,b_n]$ give you a confidence interval that contains $p$. Hence $k\approx P(\hat\theta)\in[a_n,b_n]$ and you can easily compute this probability from binomial distribution. As $n$ changes, the interval changes but $\hat\theta_n$ also changes and both changes are discrete so you get jumps. Discrete != continuous.